# Active Admin with Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, rails-api

A friend of mine and I are building an app from the scratch and both of us are in doubt of using the Active Admin gem, which is awesome and we would like to use.

Our app is built on react and an api written using ruby on rails.

We don't know if the best way is to use another rails app using the same database or to not use active admin and use some react tool for it.

Comment: See [A Rock Solid, Modern Web Stack—Rails 5 API + ActiveAdmin + Create React App on Heroku](https://blog.heroku.com/a-rock-solid-modern-web-stack).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Active admin` gem provides a good UI and routes to handle all the management. If you want to use active admin with react it would not be very easy as it provides tons of inbuilt functionality. I would suggest using Active admin for the admin management with the rails routes and for the remaining app, you can continue using react UI.

If you want to enhance your UI you can use this [gem](https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We did not know this active admin addons gem, we are also considering it now. But  maybe it is not a bad idea to use another rails app over the same database only for the administration.. what do you think?

Comment: why do you need another app if all you just can do is set a namespace, I think which already `active admin` gem provide. So whatever your admin routes will come under `admin/`.All you need to set up is login. It will save your headache of maintaining two apps

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you!